# VBoxManage list vm details (storage)

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to list details of a VirtualBox VM, from the *command line* - not from the GUI. I am especially interested in the storage details.

When I click on a VM in the GUI, I can see details including the storage section:

[image]

But I haven't found so far a way to do this via the command line.

I am on 16.04 and use

```
VBoxManage --version
5.1.22r115126
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
VBoxManage list vms -l
```

will list many details for each vm, including the storage controllers:

```
Storage Controller Name (0):            SATAController
Storage Controller Type (0):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
SATAController (0, 0): /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/vm/box-disk1.vmdk
```

To get the storage capacity,

```
VBoxManage list hdds
```

will yield something like:

```
UUID:           188d5da1-ec54-4f06-bdf1-a4435db40cf28
Parent UUID:    base
State:          locked write
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/vm/box-disk1.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       40960 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```